# Angular2 Update View After Form Submission

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm creating a simple CRUD application using Angular2.  The app consists of a table to list current records and a form to submit new records.  What's the correct way to update my table to reflect the new record after I submit the form?  Here's what I have so far.

```
export class PersonForm {
  data: Object;
  loading: boolean;

  personForm: ControlGroup;
  constructor(private _peopleService: PeopleService, personFormBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.personForm = personFormBuilder.group({
      'name': [],
      'age': []
    });
  }

  onSubmit(values:any) : void {
    console.log(values);
    this._peopleService.createPerson(values).subscribe()
  }
}
```

In the above, I'm assuming `.subscribe()` is where you'll handle the callback to update the view?

And here's that view:

```
<h1>People</h1>
  <table class="ui celled small table ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="#person of people">
      <td>
        {{person.name}}
      </td>
        <td>
        {{person.age}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
<person-form></person-form>
</div>
```

And here's the form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="personForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(personForm.value)" class="ui form">

  <div class="field">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input id="nameInput" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" [ngFormControl]="personForm.controls['name']">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input id= "ageInput" type="text" placeholder="Age" [ngFormControl]="personForm.controls['age']">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="ui button blue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your view's component you will need to set an event listener. Let's call that `PersonComponent` for now since I don't know what you've called it.

```
export class PersonComponent{
    person = {};

    updatePerson(person){
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

Then in your `PersonForm` you will need to set an `EventEmitter`

```
export class PersonForm {
    data: Object;
    loading: boolean;
    personUpdated: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    ...

    onSubmit(values:any) : void {
        console.log(values);
        this._peopleService.createPerson(values).subscribe((person) => {
            this.personUpdated.emit(person);
        });
    }
}
```

Finally you'll subscribe to the event in you `PersonComponent` which will listen to the `personUpdated` event and run the `updatePerson` method with the value of that event.

```
<person-form (personUpdated)="updatePerson($event)"></person-form>
```