# Angular2 and Services to share form data with component on same page

Tags: angular, angular-services

I apologize after refining my search string I was able to find a question with a similar request and answer: [Angular2 Update View After Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164879/angular2-update-view-after-form-submission)

I am working through and exercise that require me to create a form with 3 inputs in column #1 and an HTML table in column #2.

Column #2's HTML Table is populated with an external JSON array. BUT what I am trying to accomplish is to append the data submitted by the user to the end of the current table in a new row.

I have both the form and table components on the page and working separately.

**QUESTION:** During my research I have came across the Services option to share data between components that do not have a child parent relationship. Is this the best way to accomplish this?

**Below are my component files:**

**task-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-table',
  templateUrl: './task-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-table.component.css']
})
export class TaskTableComponent implements OnInit {

title = 'Existing Task';
  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  arrTask: string [];

  ngOnInit () {
      //console.log("Before Parse");
    this.httpService.get('./assets/task-json.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrTask = data as string [];    // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        //console.log(this.arrTask[1]);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**task-form.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { TaskObject } from '../task-object';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-form',
  templateUrl: './task-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-form.component.css']
})
export class TaskFormComponent{

  model = new TaskObject(0,'First Task', '05/20/19', 'Miguel Blanco');

  submitted = false;

  onSubmit() { this.submitted = true;} 

}
```

**task-object.ts**

```
export class TaskObject {

      constructor(
    public id: number,
    public taskName: string,
    public taskDate: string,
    public taskAssigned: string
  ) {  }

}
```

I am not sure of next steps any direct or recommendations would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using a service is the only way to share data between components that do not have a parent child relationship.

First, create a service with a `Subject` as a property

```
export class MyTransferService {

  subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  transfer = (data: any) => {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }
}
```

Register the service a singleton in the `providers` array in the metadata for `app.module`.

```
providers: [ 
  MyTransferService,'
  // other singleton services
]
```

To send data from a component, inject the service into the sending component and call the  `transfer` method where needed. It's as simple as that.

There's a little more setup required on the receiving end. First, add a `Subscription` property in the receiving component:

```
private transferSubscription: Subscription;
```

Then, in the component `OnInit`, instantiate the Subscription by subscribing to the observable obtained from the service's subject:

```
const obs = this.transferService.subject.asObservable();
this.transferSubscription = obs.subscribe(next => {
  // handle transferred data
});
```

Finally, you need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks. Have the receiving component implement `OnDestroy` and call unsubscribe on the `Subscription` property.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.transferSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful I am going to try and implement my service based on your answer. Thanks! +1